# gwt upgrade from 2.7 to 2.8.1 get exception DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory class not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jdo

I develop application with gwt 
I try to upgrade from gwt 2.7 to 2.8.1 and i get exception when create PersistenceManagerFactory 
i use google app engine 1.9.51 
this is my code to create PersistenceManagerFactory

```
public final class PMF {

    private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance;

    static {
        Map<String,String> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
        props.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "appengine");
        props.put("javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead", "true");
        props.put("javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite", "true");
        props.put("javax.jdo.option.RetainValues", "true");
        props.put("datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns", "true");
        pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(props);
    }
   // private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory( "transactions-optional" ) ;
    private PMF() {
    }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

this is exception i get

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory was not found.|NestedThrowables:|java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1175)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at com.darimpo.server.persist.PMF.<clinit>(PMF.java:25)
    at com.darimpo.server.managers.BuildingsManager.getBuildingPlaces(BuildingsManager.java:654)
    at com.darimpo.server.servlets.GreetingServiceImpl.pullBuildingPlaces(GreetingServiceImpl.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
```

this is my classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="test">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/commons-io-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/dropbox-core-sdk-V2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gagawa-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/GWT FX v0.5.0 MS 1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gwt-charts-0.9.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gwt-visualization.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gwtbootstrap3-0.9.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gwtexporter-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/gwtphonegap-3.5.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/jxl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/jars/mgwt-2.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

what i can do to fix this
thank you

Comment: put the class in the classpath perhaps?

Comment: can you explain more? I edit and add my classpath thank you

Comment: ClassNotFoundException ? Java cannot find that class in any of the jars you have there. The class being "org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory". So you have to find where it is and put that jar in the CLASSPATH. Basic java

Comment: yes I know that. this class is in google app engine 1.9.51 sdk, before the upgrade to gwt 2.8.1 there was no exception , do mean that I need to put sdk in classpath? how to do that? what do I need to add to my class path in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many options to give a simple answer.  <del>Probably your best solution is to go to the datanucleus web site and follow their "Getting Started" instructions.</del>  I stand corrected.  My apologies.

Comment: correct in terms of impossible to give an answer without more info, but the software he is using is not from the DataNucleus project and is actually Google incorrectly naming their software as DataNucleus even though it simply uses some of it at a low level